# Sorting a DataGridView by Number or Date in a Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

I have a DataGridView on a C# Forms Application I'm trying to sort.

Originally I wanted to sort by the date, but when sorting it treats it like a string.
Example:

22/9/2009
14/4/2008
3/12/2007

Sorts to

14/4/2008
22/9/2009
3/12/2007

Because its only looking at the first character.
Once I couldnt solve this I tried to sort by an ID column.  Since my data is stored by date anyways I figured I could give them an ID when loading and sort off that, but the same issue occurs.  11 comes before 2 because it starts with a 1 kinds deal.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Here is my code for reading in the data:

```
string[] rowArray = new string[] { arService[0], arService[1], arService[2], arService[3], arService[4], arService[5], arService[6] };
dgvSubmissions.Rows.Add(rowArray);
```

The array is read in from a comma delimited text file and split.

Here's my new code, but it's still providing the same results.  What am I doing wrong now?

```
  int n = dgvSubmissions.Rows.Add();
  dgvSubmissions.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = arService[0];
  dgvSubmissions.Rows[n].Cells[1].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
  dgvSubmissions.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = arService[1];
  dgvSubmissions.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = arService[2];
  n++;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data is `string`. Convert them to `DateTime`.

```
DateTime.Parse(s)
```